# No LyX preferences file on Mac

Tags: lyx

I just installed LyX on Mac OS Monterey. I am trying to change the colour scheme but there is no `preferences` file under `~/Library/Application Support/Lyx-2.3`. What am I missing?

Comment: If you open LyX, and then change a preference, and then click on "OK", then I think the preference file will be generated. Does that work?

Comment: Thanks. This worked. If you submit this suggestion as an answer I wil accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open LyX, then go to the preferences dialog, change a preference, and then click on "OK", then the preferences file will be generated.